# MigraDoc: Can I draw lines crossing out a section?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using PDFsharp/MigraDoc to create a MigraDoc document invoice for printing with a thermal-printer. I used MigraDoc basically, as I only needed paragraphs with text and images. The thing now is that in some scenarios I have to point out that the bill is cancelled with a cross out. I'm afraid I can't do it with MigraDoc but with PDFsharp. 
Can I mix both and still print it as a MigraDoc document?

**Update**
Apparently there's no way for translating a PDFsharp document to a MigraDoc one.
As I will need to use both, I'll have to work the other way building a MigraDoc and translating it to PDFsharp format. Once I've done this, I need to Preview and Print using PDFSharp's library, which I'm not being able at the moment...

I have added a PagePreview in the [Design] (I am using WinForms) but I don't know how to populate it with de PDFSharp document...

Code snippet:

```
//Render a pdf
        PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false);
        pdfRenderer.Document = document;
        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        //Draw some lines
        var page = pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Pages[0];

        PageInfo pageInfo = pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.FormattedDocument.GetPageInfo(1);
        page.Width = pageInfo.Width;
        page.Height = pageInfo.Height;
        page.Orientation = pageInfo.Orientation;

        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        {
            gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 15, page.Height / 2, page.Width -15, 2 * page.Height / 3);
            gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, page.Width - 15, page.Height / 2, 15, 2 * page.Height / 3);
        }

        string filename = "Invoice.pdf";
        pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);

        //this.pagePreview1 ...
```

*document* is the **MigraDoc** document. In the end I have *Invoice.pdf* which is correctly formed. Now, **How can I show this pdf in the PdfSharp.Forms.PagePreview** I've added to my Form?

And after that, **How should I print it?**

Comment: PDFsharp does not preview PDF files in the preview and it does not print PDF files. I suggested a "MigraDoc only" approach in my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the updated question: I would try to make a "MigraDoc only" approach.

I would create an image with the cross - otherwise the image should be transparent.
I would add this image to the page footer and I would give it an absolute position and absolute size so it fills the entire page.

By making it part of the footer, MigraDoc will repeat the image on every page.

Diagonal lines from a raster image will not be perfectly smooth, but it should be OK for a thermal printer if you make the image with the cross big enough (1000x1000 pixel or 2000x2000 pixel or so).

Comment: Thanks. Although the pdf generated looks perfect... if there's no way I'll have to try your approach. I will come back when I get it done.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I did it a little different because I didn't wat the cross to cover the whole page, so I added the image to a section and gave it Relative positioning according to the Margings and paragraphs I wanted to cover. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can mix MigraDoc and PDFsharp only for creating PDF files.

Since you create a PDF invoice, there is no problem mixing them to create pages with a cross.

Here is sample code that draws pages from MigraDoc using an own XGraphics object:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3172

After calling `pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, i);` in that loop you can use the `gfx` object to draw lines or other objects onto the page.

Comment: Thanks again Bally! now I can draw lines in the pdf rendered document but, is there anyway to turn it back to 'MigraDoc' document after the drawings? because the DocumentPreview and the the Printing method are based on the MigraDoc format... the ones I'm using.

Comment: Also, I'm avoiding to print it as a pdf because I've read that when doing so the Acrobat pops up for printing. Maybe not as exactly but some undesirable side-effect. Sorry that I still haven't tried it, just talking by hearsay...

Comment: @Joster If you use the `MigraDocPrintDocument` class for printing (which contradicts the question as you ask it) then my answer does not help you and a different approach for adding the cross would be needed. Are you printing directly from MigraDoc using `MigraDocPrintDocument`?

Comment: that is the case, I will edit my question to make it clear. I need it to be a MigraDoc document in the end for these reasons. I'm looking for doing it vice versa, creating a pdf document with the cross at first, and rendering it to MigraDoc (I could predict the positioning of the cross as it will always have the same format).